# Unable to load configuration files from classpath with Java 10

Tags: java, java-9, java-10

We are upgrading our project from Java 8 to 10. Say our project dir is:

```
/home/someuser/project
                  ├───── config
                  │        ├──── dev
                  │        └──── prod
                  └───── sources
                           ├──── projectname/common
                           │                   └──── module-info.java
                           └──── projectname/restapi
                                               └──── module-info.java
```

The `restapi` is a spring based rest controller that uses the common module. It also needs a file `dev.properties` from the classpath which is present in `config/dev`. Unfortuntely I am unable to make the files available at runtime as a part of the classpath since the config files are not part of any module. The exception we are getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.projectname.some.configuration.file]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ***class path resource*** [dev.properties] cannot be opened because it **does not exist**

How can I go about resolving this issue? Passing the dev folder as a part of the class path doesn't help. Any comment would be welcome. Regards.

Comment: Well, first I would enable as much debugging as possible for the `org.springframework` package and below so that I got some more useful output as to what actual problem it might be having.

Comment: @markspace I don't think it's a spring framework issue as the code was working with Java 8. In any case what the code does (the part that causes the exception) is:

\@PropertySources({
        \@PropertySource("classpath:${env}.properties")
})

So it basically just adds a \@PropertySource. I can't imagine how it could be the issue.

Comment: Your post suggested you've upgraded from JDK 8 to JDK 10 and you've migrated your code to modules at the same time. That is two steps and you probably need to get used to JDK 10 (or 11) before going through the process of migrating to modules.